# Count instances of specific string in Email

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012, vbscript, outlook, outlook-addin

I've looked for similar questions regarding this with no luck. I currently have working code that looks for a specific instance of string in the email body and subject. Upon finding this string, it has userform that takes it in another direction. My intentions are to have it run through the entire email and count how many times it finds this iteration and give that a callable variable for that userform(popup). Here is my code. It comes back with an error that says "InvalidCastException" so i'm guessing this is a conversion error. Any ideas? Thanks!

---

Ok so I added your comments together and came up with the following. I'm getting alot of errors, as the regex.Pattern I'm assuming doesn't exist. Any ideas? Also thank you for the literature.

```
    Dim regEx   ' Create variable.
    Dim numfound As Integer
    regEx = New RegExp   ' Create a regular expression.
    'Here it tells me that the regEx.Patter doesn't exist or Pattern is a member of the regex class
    regEx.Pattern = "\*#{9}\*" ' Set pattern.
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True   ' Set case insensitivity.
    regEx.Global = True   ' Set global applicability.
    If regEx.Execute(mailItem.Body) Then
        ' Getting a "not declared" runtime what should it be declared a Integer such as Dim numfound as Object
        numfound = regEx.count
    End If
```

---

Did some more digging and basically I'm back where I started with an InvalidCastException,

Conversion from string "111111111

123121233

" to type 'Long' is not valid.

Basically in the body of my test email I had those two strings of numbers and it can't convert them to a string to then run through the regexp iteration. Any ideas?

```
Dim sBody : sBody = (mailItem.Body) Or (mailItem.Subject) 'This is where is gives me the error
    Dim Search : Search = New RegExp
    Search.Global = True
    Search.Pattern = "\*#{9}\*"
    MsgBox(Search.Execute(sBody).Count, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
```

Comment: Do you have the right reference included in your project (Is this VBA or VBscript? I think that your pattern isn't right - you don't want "literal `*`" do you? You probably mean `.*\d{9}.*` to mean "anything followed by nine digits followed by anything".

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, if you want to use a RegExp:

(1) Start your reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

(2) Demo code to give you food for thought:

```
>> Dim sBody : sBody = "Three instances of ###: ### and a part of ####."
>> Dim Search : Set Search = New RegExp
>> Search.Global = True
>> Search.Pattern = "#{3,3}"
>> WScript.Echo Search.Execute(sBody).Count
>>
3
>>
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to do this would be just create an instance of RegEx and use it to parse the Item.Body.

```
Set Search = new RegExp
Search.IgnoreCase = True
Search.Global = True

Search.Pattern = "\*#{9}\*"
If Search.Test(Item.Body) Then
   'will hold how many times it has been found
   numFound = Search.Count
End If
```

Here is a link with a bit more information on RegExp http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Comment: -1 for fantasy code. .Test does not affect its object; .Count is a property of the Match Collection returned by .Execute.